# How to get disabled entities in TYPO3 8.x extbase?

Tags: doctrine, repository, typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I've set up a simple repository query setting to get certain fe_user in TYPO3 CMS 8.7.22. Without disable this fe_user the repository gives back the expected entity.

But after disable the object again the repository returns `null`. So why `setIgnoreEnableFields` and `setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored` doesn't work anymore?

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
$defaultQuerySettings = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
$defaultQuerySettings->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);
$defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(TRUE);
$defaultQuerySettings->setIgnoreEnableFields(TRUE);
$defaultQuerySettings->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(array('disable'));

$someRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($defaultQuerySettings);
$response = $someRepository->findByIdentifier($fe_user_id);
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Okay I guess it's the findByUid from the default fe user repository that denies this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `findByUid` function from the default `frontendUserRepsository`. There they prevent to get hidden / deleted objects. So I build my own repository function for that case:

```
public function findHiddenByUid($uid){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $qs = clone($this->defaultQuerySettings);
    $qs->setIgnoreEnableFields(TRUE);
    $qs->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['disable','hidden','disabled']);
    $query->setQuerySettings($qs);
    $query->matching($query->equals('uid', $uid));
    return $query->execute()->getFirst();
}
```